# Making application visible to software audit tools

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, installation, audit

I'm writing a software for Windows which is not always installed via msi installer.
The software is aimed for business customers.
Bigger companies use tools to audit software installed on employee machines.

My question is:
Is there any standard way to make my software visible to these tools.
Perhaps there is a place in Windows Registry where I should register my application?

Comment: Typically this would be done via an Add/Remove Programs entry, aka an uninstall entry.  Even if you don't actually ship an uninstaller (though you should) you can still create such an entry.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with the details, but try searching MSDN for Add/Remove Programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the standard registry key **\Software\[YourCompanyName]\[YourProductName]** in **[HKLM]** or in **[HKCU]**, and in that key you can create a "Default Registry Value"

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx) for more info on how to create registry keys in C#.

Hope this helps.